# How to access scope from an event inside a controller?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, events, dom, scope

I have a div element and a ng-click event handler attached to it. something like

```
<div ng-controller='controller' ng-click='handle($event)'>
  <div ng-repeat='foo in foos'>{{foo.name}}</div>
</div>
```

When user clicks on foo.name, i could capture the event but it seems that i couldn't access the isolated scope created by ng-repeat.

I try following this path getEvent->getTarget->getBindedScope.

actual codes are something like

```
var a = $($event.target)
var ac = a.scope();
```

but when i do

```
console.log(ac);
```

the stuff logged out is "undefined".

What i wish to achieve here is accessing that scope and get other stuff out. Such as foo.id or foo.someproperty

Lots of appreciation for the help in advance.

PS:I know this is not the angularjs way, but I wish to achieve due to some other reasons.

PS2: $event.target is tried. logging result is something like

Comment: Try logging a $event.target and post the response.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZD3hOb1OKYzy26ELpudp?p=preview

Comment: @tasseKATT thanks man that works like a charm in plunker. But i am still getting 'undefined' printed out in my actual project. so sad.

Comment: Can you show more code? The way to get the isolated scope is a.isolateScope(), but I don't think ng-repeat creates one. Do you have another directive attached with an isolate scope? Try a.isolateScope() then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly clear on what you are trying to do (I don't use jQuery that much, and not with AngularJS), but I get that you want access to the foo object (or other aspects of that item's scope) inside the ngRepeat from the ngClick method.

Could you not do this instead?

```
<div ng-controller='controller'>
  <div ng-repeat='foo in foos' ng-click='$parent.handle($event)'>{{foo.name}}</div>
</div>
```

That way you are calling the parent controller's handle() method (due to the ***$parent*** prefix) from within the ngRepeat item's isolated scope.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: indeed. i think maybe bottom-up is a clearer solution.